# Swift generics - Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to call a generic function and i get this error:

> Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

My code:

```
public func parse<T: Codable>(request: HTTPRequestProtocol,
                              completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
          ///....
}
```

//

```
parser.parse<Person>(request: request, onSuccess: { (codable)  in
         //Error: Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
}
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is this rule in Swift that you must not explicitly say (using `<>`s) what the generic parameters of a generic method are. You must give clues to the type inference engine to let *it* figure the generic parameters out. In this case, you can annotate the type of closure parameter, so that the closure has a type of `(Person) -> Void`. With this information, the compiler can figure the type of `T` out.

```
parser.parse(request: request, onSuccess: { (codable: Person)  in ... }
```

In other cases, you might have to take in an extra parameter of type `T.Type`. For example, if your function only takes a type parameter and no value parameters:

```
func foo<T>() { ... }
```

In that case, you'd need to add an extra parameter:

```
func foo<T>(_ type: T.Type) { ... }
```

so that you can use it as:

```
foo(Person.self)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also take a param like `_: T.Type`, whose argument would be something like `String.self`, much like how Decodable does it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unkeyeddecodingcontainer